# Are these negations of statements correct?

Tags: logic

For each statement given, I had to write a negation then decide which of the two is true, would anyone check them for me?

Statement: For each $n∈\mathbb{N}$, there is $m∈\mathbb{N}$ such that $n\leq m$.  **TRUE**

Negation: There exists $n∈\mathbb{N}$ such that for each $m∈\mathbb{N}$, $n>m$.

Statement: There is $n∈\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $m∈\mathbb{N}, n\leq m$.  **TRUE**

Negation: For each $n∈\mathbb{N}$, there exists $m∈\mathbb{N}$ such that $n> m$.

Statement: There is $m∈\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n∈\mathbb{N}, n\leq m$.  **TRUE**

Negation: For each $m∈\mathbb{N}$, there exists $n∈\mathbb{N}$ such that $n>m$.

Statement: For each non-zero $x∈\mathbb{R}$, there is $y∈\mathbb{R}$ such that $xy=1$.  **TRUE**

Negation: There exists non-zero $x∈\mathbb{R}$, such that for all $y∈\mathbb{R}$ $xy\ne1$.

Statement: There is $x∈\mathbb{R}$ such that for all $y∈\mathbb{R}$, $xy=1$.

Negation: For each $x∈\mathbb{R}$, there exists $y∈\mathbb{R}$, $xy\ne1$.

Statement: There is $x∈\mathbb{R}$ such that for all $y∈\mathbb{R}$, $xy=0$.  **TRUE**

Negation: For each $x∈\mathbb{R}$, there exists $y∈\mathbb{R}$ such that $xy\ne0$.

Comment: The negation of "for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, blah blah" is "there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that NOT[blah blah]" ...

Comment: Ah thanks.  So for example the statement: For each $n∈\mathbb{N}$, there is $m∈\mathbb{N}$ such that $n\leq m$, the negation should be: There exists $n∈\mathbb{N}$ such that there isn't $m∈\mathbb{N}, n\leq m$?

Comment: Close vote: why should anyone on MSE filter your homework answers before you get them marked?

Comment: @MikeA: Also, the negation of "there exists $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that ..." is "for each $m\in\mathbb{N}$, NOT[...]".

Comment: No-one should feel obligated and I'm sure no-one does feel obligated to help me out.  If someone does take the time to do so, then that is kind of them and I appreciate it.

Comment: @Adren Nearly all of them need a reevaluation by myself, I wasn't nearly stringent enough with the logic, cheers for pointing these out.

Comment: @MikeA: You are welcome. Now try to adjust everything and edit the OP.

Comment: @Adren will do, I was wondering whether I should edit the post.

Comment: @MikeA: anyone who feels inclined to filter your homework answers is providing a homework help service that isn't what I thought MSE was for.

Comment: @Rob Arthan Well I've learnt something about logic and negating statements, and ultimately the site is about educating people, unless my interpretation is wrong.

Comment: @MikeA: so what would be the educational value to you of a literal answer to your question? MSE is **not** a homework answering service.

Comment: @RobArthan I have attempted a question for which I don't have access to the correct answer.  If my answer is correct and I don't know that is the case, then I can't have confidence that I have understood the material covered in said question.  If my answer is incorrect, then knowing it is a mistake allows me the opportunity to try and learn from it, which I can't do if I don't know it is wrong. That is the educational value of a literal answer and that is not including other advice I have gained in the thread that wasn't a literal answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple statements like these, you can develop an intuition by forming them in natural language, negating that, and then rephrasing the negation mathematically. To use your first problem,

> For each $n \in N$, there exists $m \in N$ such that $n < m$.

This is saying

> There's always a larger natural number.

The negation of which is

> There is a largest natural number

Which is expressed mathematically as

> There exists $n \in N$ such that for all $m \in N$, $n \ge m$.

Try this with your other statements. You should notice a pattern in how a statement relates to its negation. Additionally, phrasing it in natural language will probably help you figure out its truth value.

Comment: Thanks for you comment, that's a very helpful explanation!  I'm gonna work through these again with this in mind.  Is this a good start? Statement: There is $n∈\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $m∈\mathbb{N}, n\leq m$.  

Negation: For each $n∈\mathbb{N}$, there exists $m∈\mathbb{N}$ such that $n>m$.  So the statement in plain english would be: There is a smallest natural number and plain english negation: There's always a smaller number.